# Самообучение агента на LSTM нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Хочу сделать простого 2D агента на LSTM (именно LSTM) нейросети. Который ходит по карте, ест зеленые точки и избегает красных

Как сделать чтобы он всегда обучался и оставался адекватным?

Видел алгоритм когда боту рандомно генерируют направление и скорость и поощряют или наказывают его в зависимости от того, на что он нарвался. В итоге у него есть 2 режима "дерганое обучение" и "обычное поведение" где в ходе последнего он уже не обучается.

Так вот, как сложить эти 2 состояния? Чтобы агент всегда обучался